# Improve performance of importing 2 CSV files, comparing, grouping, and outputting results to a log

Tags: performance, powershell, refactoring, powershell-4.0

I am pretty new to powershell in general so I would like some suggestions on how to improve the performance of my code. The goal of this script is to import 2 CSV files, compare between them, and output the results to a log file (or two, depending on the option selected).

My original script here works fine, but is not very fast. In my test environment, it takes about 15 seconds to import, compare, group, and output logs for all ~440 files contained in the two CSV files. 15s isn't much, but I will be running this script against 600,000+ files, so the faster the better.

```
#User variables
$logpath = "X:\Documents\Customer Projects"
$passlog = $true

$startt = (Get-Date)

# code to check to see if necessary files exist and/or are locked is here

$csv1 = Import-CSV $generated
$csv2 = Import-CSV $cloud
$comp = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $csv2 -DifferenceObject $csv1 -Property Name,Size,Hash -PassThru
$group = $comp | Group-Object -Property Name
$failcount = ($group | Measure-Object).count
If ($passlog) {
    $comp = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $csv2 -DifferenceObject $csv1 -IncludeEqual -Property Name,Size,Hash
    $group = $comp | Group-Object -Property Name
    $count = ($group | Measure-Object).count
}
Else {
    $count = $failcount
}
$curr = 0
Write-Output "($failcount) files failed verification. See logs and below for details:"
Write-Output "`n"
foreach ($file in $group)
{
    $source = $comp | Where-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" -and $_.Name -eq $file.name)}
    $dest = $comp | Where-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" -and $_.Name -eq $file.name)}
    $pass = $comp | Where-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "==" -and $_.Name -eq $file.name)}
    $name = $file.name
    $sourcesize = $source | Select -ExpandProperty Size
    $sourcehash = $source | Select -ExpandProperty Hash
    $destsize = $dest | Select -ExpandProperty Size
    $desthash = $dest | Select -ExpandProperty Hash
    $destpath = ($csv1 | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $file.name} | Select -ExpandProperty DestPath)
    $countp = ($file | Select -ExpandProperty Count)
    $curr += 1
    $logger = $true
    if ($countp -ge 2 -and ($source) -and ($dest)) {
        Write-Host "($curr of $count) Hash mis-match            -"$file.name""
        $message = "Hash mis-match"
    }
    if ($countp -eq 1 -and ($pass)) {
        Write-Host "($curr of $count) Verification passed!      -"$file.name""
        $message = "Verification passed"
        $sourcesize = ($pass | Select -ExpandProperty Size)
        $sourcehash = ($pass | Select -ExpandProperty Hash)
        $destsize = $sourcesize
        $desthash = $sourcehash
        $logger = $false
    }
    if ($countp -eq 1 -and ($source)) {
        Write-Host "($curr of $count) Missing from destination  -"$file.name""
        $message = "File missing from destination"
    }
    if ($countp -eq 1 -and ($dest)) {
        Write-Host "($curr of $count) Missing from source       -"$file.name""
        $message = "File missing from source"
    }
    If ($logger) {
        $whichlog = $failed   
    }
    Else {
        $whichlog = $passed
    }
    "" | Select @{Name="Status";Expression={$message}},@{N="FileName";E={$name}},@{N="SourceSize";E={$sourcesize}},@{N="SourceHash";E={$sourcehash}},@{N="DestSize";E={$destsize}},@{N="DestinationHash";E={$desthash}},@{N="DestinationPath";E={$destpath}} | Export-Csv -Path $whichlog -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
$endt = (Get-Date)
$runt = ($endt - $startt)
$exectime = "$($runt.hours)h:$($runt.minutes)m:$($runt.seconds)s"
Write-Output "`n"
Write-Output "Completed in $exectime! Press any key to close...";
```

I have read about improving performance using hashtables and not appending to files or arrays. I haven't figured out how to use hashtables properly, but refactoring to write to the CSV all at once at the end of the script instead of appending each run through the loop provides a good performance boost. Using the below changes drops the time down to 10 seconds, which is a nice improvement, but I feel that 10s is still far too long.

```
# same code before this point
Write-Host "Starting verification process. This may take some time..."
$array = foreach ($file in $group)
{
    $source = $comp | Where-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" -and $_.Name -eq $file.name)}
    $dest = $comp | Where-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" -and $_.Name -eq $file.name)}
    $pass = $comp | Where-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "==" -and $_.Name -eq $file.name)}
    $name = $file.name
    $sourcesize = $source.size
    $sourcehash = $source.hash
    $destsize = $dest.size
    $desthash = $dest.hash
    $destpath = ($csv1 | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $file.name} | Select -ExpandProperty DestPath)
    $countp = ($file | Select -ExpandProperty Count)
    $curr += 1
    $logger = $true
    if ($countp -eq 1 -and ($pass)) {
        Write-Host "($curr of $count) Verification passed!      -"$file.name""
        $message = "Verification passed"
        $sourcesize = ($pass.size)
        $sourcehash = ($pass.hash)
        $destsize = $sourcesize
        $desthash = $sourcehash
    }
    if ($countp -ge 2 -and ($source) -and ($dest)) {
        #Write-Host "($curr of $count) Hash mis-match            -"$file.name""
        $message = "Hash mis-match"
    }
    if ($countp -eq 1 -and ($source)) {
        #Write-Host "($curr of $count) Missing from destination  -"$file.name""
        $message = "File missing from destination"
    }
    if ($countp -eq 1 -and ($dest)) {
        #Write-Host "($curr of $count) Missing from source       -"$file.name""
        $message = "File missing from source"
    }
    $file | Select @{N="Status";E={$message}},@{N="FileName";E={$name}},@{N="SourceSize";E={$sourcesize}},@{N="SourceHash";E={$sourcehash}},@{N="DestinationSize";E={$destsize}},@{N="DestinationHash";E={$desthash}},@{N="DestinationPath";E={$destpath}}
}
$array | Where-Object {$_.Status -ne "Verification passed"} | Export-Csv -Path $failed -NoTypeInformation
If ($passlog) {
    $array | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Verification passed"} | Export-Csv -Path $passed -NoTypeInformation
}
# same code after this point
```

I believe the next logical step would be to somehow get all of the needed information into one place so that the `ForEach` loop can quickly lookup the data needed rather than having to sort, filter, or otherwise do unnecessary calculations. I did try to do this as seen in the below code and then ran a second loop to grab the fields and generate the status message, but the performance of this was worse than my original (probably due to more filtering for the first `ForEach` loop by comparison to the original). Any suggestions?

```
$array = ForEach ($item in $group) {
    $name = $item.name
    $count = $item.Count
    $SideInd = $comp | Where-Object {($_.Name -eq ($item.name))} | Select -ExpandProperty SideIndicator
    $SourceS = $csv2 | Where-Object {($_.Name -eq ($item.name))} | Select -ExpandProperty Size
    $SourceH = $csv2 | Where-Object {($_.Name -eq ($item.Name))} | Select -ExpandProperty Hash
    $DestS = $csv1 | Where-Object {($_.Name -eq $item.Name)} | Select -ExpandProperty Size
    $DestH = $csv1 | Where-Object {($_.Name -eq $item.Name)} | Select -ExpandProperty Hash
    $DestP = $csv1 | Where-Object {($_.Name -eq $item.Name)} | Select -ExpandProperty DestPath
    $Item | Select name, count, @{N="SideInd";E={$SideInd}}, @{N="SourceSize";E={$SourceS}}, @{N="SourceHash";E={$SourceH}}, @{N="DestinationSize";E={$DestS}}, @{N="DestinationHash";E={$DestH}}, @{N="DestinationPath";E={$DestP}}
}
```

Comment: Any time you're doing $variable | Cmdlet, look for the parameter that takes pipeline input and use it directly.  For instance, Group-Object -inputobject $comp -Property Name

Comment: Also, consider using the .Where() method on collections instead of the where-object cmdlet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Which version of powershell are you using? [Powershell Core](https://github.com/powershell/powershell) is much faster...